# Exchange 2010: E-mail address policies processing order

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2010

I already have a tested assumption on this but I want to find documentation:

I have 2 e-mail address policy. `Policy A` has a constricting condition. `Policy B` is pretty much a catch all.

1. I have to set `Policy A` with a higher (lower number) priority for this setup to work as expected correct? Otherwise, `Policy B` will catch all accounts and we will never get to `Policy A`
2. There is no way to have multiple policies processed for accounts, correct? If we want to add multiple SMTP addresses to an account, we will need to add it to one policy whose conditions will match the accounts we are interested in.

I am sorry if this is less of a question and more of a "verify my testing" request. I just rather make sure that I'm not missing anything before proceeding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Correct, set the more strict policy with a lower # priority (0).
2. Also correct, set the policy up with multiple addresses needed for the accounts that will process that policy.